# How to check logs for IPsec through windows defender firewall

Tags: windows, ipsec, libreswan

The steps I followed are:

Press win+R and enter gpedit.msc(Open group policy editor).

Select windows settings --> security settings --> windows defender firewall.

Right click on windows defender firewall and select properties.

There enable/allow all inbound, outbound connections and enable firewall for private, public, Domain profiles.

Now under windows defender firewall select connection rules and add rule.

Rule is a custom one, I use pre shared key authentication and select 2 local endpoints for host-host ipsec.

The ipsec is between windows and my linux containing libreswan.

When i see security associations from windows defender firewall (just go to start and type advanced windows defender firewall and there you will see  a new window.In options there, expand monitoring and see security assocations, you will see quick mode and main mode all sa there) only main mode is established and quick mode messages are being sent from linux but no response from windows.

So i need to see the logs for these in windows, so i can troubleshoot my issues.

Have tried with event viewer, not seeing any logs there. Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Anil Gowda M

I expect to see logs for the above ipsec trials, but am unable to see.